# HttpWebRequest GET with object as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, httpwebrequest, http-get

I'm trying to call an API from a Windows Service. The API is written in ASP MVC. So far, I am creating requests something like this:

```
private List<T> GetCollectionFromApi<T>(string url)
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();

        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        result.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(sr.ReadToEnd()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle err
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is all fine, but now I need to pass a parameter with my GET request. That parameter is an object, not a primitive type.

Do I deconstruct it, property by property, in a query string? Or do I add it to request header somehow? I do plan on relying on *DefaultModelBinder* in API's controller. Any plan would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same case and solved it by using POST method and put object to the request content. I had not find proper way to use the request header unfortunately

Comment: That's why I asked about GET :)

Comment: so you can deconstruct it to query string. However it will require to have controller method with parameters corresponding to object properties. And you have to modify controller method each time when property is added|removed in the object class.

Comment: _"but now I need to pass a parameter with my GET request"_ - show the controller that accepts this request, or we can't say anything about it. Also, don't use HttpWebRequest, use HttpClient.

Comment: @CodeCaster It's a simple `ApiController`, I still don't have the action method since I don't know how the data will be sent (URI, request header or something else). And why HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest?

Comment: The service determines how it should be called, not the client. You're developing this the wrong way around.

Comment: I have an API controller with an ActionMethod which returns some data, so it should be GET request, right? That is all determined on the side of the service. I'm here just trying to figure out what the best way to send that parameter is.

Comment: If it's a GET request, you should generally just use query string parameters. Alexander's answer illustrates this perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**API Side:**

You need to use `[FromUri]` attribute in your API action.

For more information about parameter binding please review this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri).

```
public class SomeData
{
    public int Start { get; set; } 
    public int End { get; set; }
}
public SomeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] SomeData data) { ... }
}
```

**Client Side**

You need send your parameters in query as usual.

```
http://localhost/api/Some?Start=0&End=10
```

Also one more interesting link for details is [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/parameter-binding-in-asp-net-web-api/).

Answer (score 0):

Does your object something like this? So multiple properties in a list or something?

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

If so you can serialize it with Json.Convert. After that you'll have a string what you can pass with you request. What specific is the object. Is it the authorisation from the asp mvc. If so you most likely will need the OAuth accesstoken.

Hope this helps

Comment: Helps somewhat. Yes, it's a simple object, only a few properties. But I still don't know where to put that JSON? In the request header?

Comment: No, you don't want to send a JSON string in a GET request.

Comment: @CodeCaster You are right, my fault. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer to handle all rest request with [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp).Also it will solve your problem.

As reporter mentioned that object will have few properties than it can be done following way without making any changes to API controller.

```
var request = new RestRequest(url).AddParameter("paramName", "paramValue", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

and you can get result by :

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Where **client** is **`RestClient`** class which handles all your request/response activity.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a link to a library. Explain how you would solve this problem with RestSharp.

Comment: `ParameterType.UrlSegment` - so you have decided that the OP uses routing for these parameters now?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have just gave him hint hence it has various ways to attach parameters with request.it has ParameterType.GetOrPost as well. see docs for more info.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Code sample in my sample will 110% solve the problem of reporter

Comment: No, it will not. The OP has an API which they want to send data to, but they don't know how they want to accept the data. Your answer assumes they want it through routing (you use `ParameterType.UrlSegment`). Sure, RestSharp may have helped you solve a similar problem in the past, but this is not the same problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster, if OP follow with code that I have provided then default ModelBinder will automatically bind incoming request parameters to model which will solve his problem. and BTW , OP doesn't know how to embed object with HttpGet request and by this way he can solve his problem

Comment: No, it will not. The UrlSegment approach uses URL segments.